# How can I stop sap from seeping out?

Tags: repair, damage

[image]

I have some sap seeping out of a fur/pine door I installed and stained last year, how do I stop that from coming out?

Answer (score 2):

On interior wood, painters use alcohol-based shellac to pre-seal knots before they prime.

Shellac blocks both oils and water for a good stain-proof seal, while also promoting adhesion between coats.

Comment: Not sure, I think he used minwax conditioner.
But I can sand it down to bare wood, then use an alcohol based shellac before staining it again?